# Is it possible to deploy 2 separate MVC apps into one Azure Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

It's been incredible exhausting for me, after passing a week to deploy MVCForum (Source Code) to my Azure Web App. I've read that it was possible if you selected a different path when publishing, something that I did. But when I tried running, my main app and the MVC Forum were conflicting between them.

I'd like to use Azure's Web Apps instead of Azure's Cloud Services because of the simplicity and the possibility of only uploading the files that have changed. I have seen that it is possible to upload Web Api and MVC in that fashion, but I have not found an example that sends 2 different MVC apps into a same Web App.

Is it possible to do it with 2 different MVC apps? (Note: Areas are not an option, since the MVC Forum Source Code resides on a completely different solution)

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jose Why not make the two applications areas in a master Asp.net MVC app? Then just config your routes however.

Comment: Hi fassetar, thanks for the reply :) how would I configure the routes in the master asp.net mvc app so that it could point them to my main app and the mvc forum? BTW, how would I migrate all that content to the master app without much hassle??

Comment: Are you trying to deploy as a single project (e.g. github repo) or separate deployments?

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Separate deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment that you are trying to work with separate deployments:

A Web App under the same name (e.g. `myapp.azurewebsites.net`) is going to be managed by a single deployment. That is, if you have two github repo's (or two dropbox folders, or two of anything) and try to push up new content from deployment B, you'll effectively wipe out deployment A.

You can certainly have multi-path apps running in the same deployment, but they'd need to be part of a single distribution (e.g. single github repo). Otherwise, you'd need multiple deployment slots (e.g. `app-a.azurewebsites.net` and `app-b.azurewebsites.net`).

Comment: Thanks David. I understand and I find it very reasonable and logical that that is what is happening. So, in other words I would need to have separate apps in order to accomplish what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use virtual directory to upload multiple app projects in single webapp, [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx) article explained it

1. Create projects
2. Assign virtual directory
3. Publish the root project
4. Set up virtual directory in azure portal
5. Publish the child projects

Comment: Hi Ansel! Thanks for the reply! Already tried that! Unfortunately, my main app conflicted with the forum!!!